# Cannot implicitly convert type DbDataReader to MySqlDataReader when using ExecuteReaderAsync

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await

I've the following function that allows me to pass in a object and populate that object with the returning data, if any.

I've modified the function so that it can be called asynchronously.

```
public static async Task<MySqlDataReader> MySQLReturnReader(string sName, List<MySqlParameter> oParameters, Action<MySqlDataReader> fn)
{
    using (MySqlConnection oConn = new MySqlConnection(MasterConn))
    {
        await oConn.OpenAsync();

        using (MySqlCommand oMySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(sName, oConn))
        {
           oMySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (oParameters != null)
            {
                foreach (MySqlParameter oPar in oParameters)
                {
                    oMySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(oPar);
                }
            }

            oMySqlCommand.Connection.Open();

            using (MySqlDataReader oReader = oMySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
               fn(oReader);
            }

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

My class object is something like;

```
public class MyClass
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     ...
}
```

The function can be called like

```
 List<MyClass> oMyClassList = new List<MyClass>();
 List<MySqlParameter> oParams = new List<MySqlParameter>();

 List<int> Ids = new List<int>(500);
 Ids.Add(1);
 Ids.Add(2);
 ...
 Ids.Add(499);

 foreach(int Id in Ids)
 {
    MySQLReturnReader("SPCheck", oParams, oRes =>
        {
                while (oRes.Read())
                {
                   MyClass oMyClass = new MyClass();                      
                   oMyClass.Id = Convert.ToInt32(oRes["Id"]);                       
                   oMyClass.Name = oRes["Name"].ToString();
                }

                oMyClassList.Add(oMyClass);
        }
        );


 }
```

The problem is I'm getting the compilation error of 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader'.  Where am I going wrong ?

I'm wanting to use ExecuteReaderAsync in this way, as the Stored procedure called is very complex and would prefer to run the requests in parallel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This most likely indicates that the library you're using doesn't support `ExecuteReaderAsync()`, so you're just calling the default implementation inherited from `DbCommand`. This is why it returns the general `DbDataReader` (instead of the MySQL-specific one). And this also means that your code won't actually be asynchronous, the default version of `ExecuteReaderAsync()` is just a synchronous wrapper around `ExecuteReader()`.

So, I think you should directly use the old `ExecuteReader()`, until your library adds support for `ExecuteReaderAsync()`.

Comment: I understand your answer, however is there a workaround so that my call will be asynchronous ?

Comment: @Tommo1977 I don't think you can, you simply can't make synchronous library into asynchronous without modifying the library. You can always use `Task.Run()` to execute the synchronous methods, but that's not really asynchronous (it still blocks a thread).

Comment: Thanks.  How would I adapt my example to use Task.Run().  I know it wouldn't be really async, but it would allow multiple calls to the Stored procedure to be made at the same time.

Comment: MySql.Data has supported `ExecuteReaderAsync` for a long time (it just doesn't implement it properly; see my answer). The compiler error the OP posted simply means the code is lacking the `await` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have:

```
using (MySqlDataReader oReader = oMySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
```

The compiler error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader'` means that you need to use the `await` keyword to "unwrap" the task returned by `ExecuteReaderAsync`:

```
using (MySqlDataReader oReader = await oMySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
```

Note however that if you're using the official MySql.Data package, this call won't actually execute asynchronously. The `Async` methods in the `MySql.Data` connector aren't asynchronous; they block on network I/O and only return when the DB operation is complete. (For a much more detailed discussion, see [this question and its top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551459/mysql-c-sharp-async-methods-doesnt-work).) [MySQL bug #70111](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111) reports this problem in the MySQL connector.

To get truly asynchronous DB operations, you'll have to wait until that bug is fixed, or switch to a different connector. I've been developing a new, fully async connector that should be a drop-in replacement for MySql.Data; to try it out, install [MySqlConnector from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/); its [source is at GitHub](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector).