# C# MySQL Asynchronous methods not working

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous

Good day everyone. I've been using the MySQL API to interact with my MySQL database. The only problem is that the asynchronous methods aren't working.

**Example of my code:**

```
private MySqlConnection mySqlConnection;

private async Task OpenConnection() {
    //Assign mySqlConnection if null
    //Check if mySqlConnection is closed
    await mySqlConnection.OpenAsync();
}

private async Task<bool> ExampleMethod() {
    try {
        await OpenConnection();
        return true;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Whenever I execute `ExampleMethod` my application pauses until the method has completed its operation. Could someone tell me what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the `Async` methods in the `MySql.Data` connector aren't actually asynchronous. They block on network I/O and only return when the DB operation is complete. (For a much more detailed description, see [this question and its top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551459/mysql-c-sharp-async-methods-doesnt-work).) [MySQL bug #70111](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111) reports this problem in the MySQL connector.

To get truly asynchronous DB operations, you'll have to wait until that bug is fixed, or switch to a different connector. I've been developing a new, fully async connector; to try it out, install [MySqlConnector from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/); its [source is at GitHub](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector).

Answer (score 0):

The debugger *will* wait for async operations to complete, and that is by design.

`async` is primarily a tool to let you execute long-running tasks without blocking the UI, and without having to resort to using the traditional thread approaches.

The debugger will block, because there isn't any other running code to switch to.

Comment: What do you mean by _there isn't any other code to switch to_? And also I've tried running the application without debugging and the UI still freezes until the async operation is complete...