# C# Mysql executenonqueryasync is not asynchronous

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous

I want to get the list of the teachers  who are teaching this specific type:

```
public static async Task<DataTable> getTeacherSHS() 
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string query = @"some long query dont mid this";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cs))
    {
        try
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            using( MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shs", "%SHS%");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term);

                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)) 
                {
                    await da.FillAsync(dt);
                    MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }
        if (conn != null)
            await conn.CloseAsync();
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Now my method for getting this is via a button click and it will return a datatable for my datagridview

```
private  async void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = await ConnectionAsync.getTeacherSHS(); 
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
}
```

My problem is that after clicking the button the call is blocking the other I/O i cant seem to type in the other textbox because it is waiting for the task to be done. I thought it was asynchronous, can somebody explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the `Async` methods in the `MySql.Data` connector aren't actually asynchronous. They block on network I/O and only return when the DB operation is complete. (For a much more detailed description, see [this question and its top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551459/mysql-c-sharp-async-methods-doesnt-work).) [MySQL bug #70111](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111) reports this problem in the MySQL connector.

To get truly asynchronous DB operations, you'll have to wait until that bug is fixed, or switch to a different connector.

I've been developing a new, fully async connector ([MySqlConnector on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/); [source on GitHub](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector)). It supports `MySqlDataAdapter` since [version 0.33.0](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/releases/tag/0.33.0).