# Will leaving MySqlConnection idle cause it to timeout?

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

I'm currently developing game server, that uses MySQL for storage.

The question is: if I will leave MySQL Connection to idle I think it will cause it to timeout?

If yes would it be wise and possible to turn off connection idle timeout? 
Or maybe I should before every query check it out if connection hasn't been closed and open it again?

But then another question arises: Should I use async methods or create new thread that would be responsible for MySQL, in order to not pause main thread because then all the sync between players would be interrupted?

Comment: Keep the connection open for as short time as possible. Why do you want it to idle?

Comment: Because I'll need to reuse it later, for example when another player connects to load his data. Or I should open new connection then?

Comment: Yes open a new connection. Read up on connection pooling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your server settings but you must anticipate that MySQL connections will *eventually* be terminated for being idle. The amount of time that elapses before they're considered dead varies considerably.

The normal practice here is to use a connection pool that automatically recovers from connection-related errors by creating a new connection and retrying the query.

Most database drivers will return a very specific exception if you're operating on a closed connection. These can be caught and handled accordingly.

Comment: Allright That clarified the first part of the question. However, I'm not sure if I should use new thread for opening connection or atleast using async functions to do it. (sql server is in same server as my game server is.) (I'm just not really sure how long connection opening takes). Because I don't really want to halt main thread, because that may cause issues with sync between players.

Comment: Usually you'd have a connection pool or a thread pool where each thread has its own connection. Set up a work queue to distribute the work across all the connections asynchronously or directly to the threads.

Comment: Aight I see. Thanks for help. I'll mark this as the best answer.

Comment: @Kudzė I'd recommend the use of async DB methods. Note however that the `MySql.Data` library *does not implement* async database methods; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42305108 for details. I recommend the use of a MySQL ADO.NET library that I've authored that is truly async: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Comment: @BradleyGrainger How does that code handle stale/idle/killed connections?

Comment: @Kudzė If you're using connection pooling (on by default; recommended) then when `MySqlConnection` is `Dispose`d it's returned to the pool. When a new `MySqlConnection` is opened, a pooled connection is retrieved and checked for liveness. If it's dead, a new connection to the server is opened automatically (transparently to your code, slightly more expensive). Idle connections are controlled by the server's [`wait_timeout` variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) which is set to 8 hours by default.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Wow Thanks. Is it possible for me to send some kind of random query that my connection wouldn't go off when there's no activity every like 7 hours?

Comment: @Kudzė Try `SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=2147483;` to change the server's default timeout, then make sure you include `ConnectionIdleTimeout=0` in the connection string. (Usually it's not a big deal if an idle connection is closed and automatically reopened; is there a reason you need to ensure your connections aren't closed?)

Comment: Oh wait I'm an idiot if there's no activity then it means that there are no connected players in the server. So probably that reconnection wont matter anyways.