# MySql.Data with 'new Thread' vs ThreadPool: using ThreadPool creates a deadlock

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, threadpool, mysql-connector

In a project, I discovered a peculiar behavior then connecting to a MySQL instance using threads from a ThreadPool; the application froze and it looks like it is due to a deadlock inside `MySqlConnection.Open`. This does not happen when I manually create the Thread and  run the Start method.

[This project on GitHub](https://github.com/tedekeroth/ThreadPoolMySqlTests) showcases this, and I would like help understanding why it behaves this way.

- There are two methods, `TestThreads` and `TestTask`. Each method executes a for-loop that creates/spawns/fetches 200 threads, and each threads connects to a MySQL 8 server with the standard `MySqlConnection` class, sleeps for 5 seconds, and closes the connection. A Stopwatch measures the time for each method to complete.
- The `TestThreads` creates the threads manually (`new Thread()... thread.Start()`); completes in about 12-14 seconds and I see no issues.
- The `TestTask` uses the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`; it normally does not complete at all due to the deadlock that seems to be happening inside the `MySqlConnection.Open`

Here is a screenshot from running `TestTask`:

[image]

All the threads are in the `MySqlConnection.Open` method, and stays there. They don't seem to get any further to print out some log messsages - no log messages are ever produced for me running `TestTask`.

On the other hand, running `TestThreads` works, then then I get the log message I expect:

[image]

I would like to understand why ThreadPool fails when creating manual threads works? Why is MySqlConnection deadlocked in one case, but not the other?

Please note that since we are testing against the same MySQL server, it is not a MySQL configuration issue. I also don't see how it can be ThreadPool starvation; we set the MinThread to 200. Also, since I never get a single Console.WriteLine in the `TestTask` case, there must surely be something else?

Comment: Possibly related to starvation due to limited rate of ThreadPool growth and how tasks are picked up to process. That can be verified by setting the minimum thread pool size to something large and see if/how the behavior changes. https://labs.criteo.com/2018/10/net-threadpool-starvation-and-how-queuing-makes-it-worse/

Comment: This test application sets the minthreads to 200, but in other cases I tried setting it to 1000, no difference. I adjusted the value to 500 in the test project, no difference.

Comment: Have you inspected the stacktrace of the blocked threads (including external code)? You set min and max to 200, what if some other code (probably mysqlconnection or something related) also want's to start a task or a threadpool thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySql.Data has some poorly-written async code inside it (besides the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42305108/23633) that none of the `Async` methods are actually async).

For example, this code starts async work using a `Task`, then calls `Task.Wait`: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/4306c8484ec74b3ee1c349847f66acabbce6d63c/MySQL.Data/src/common/StreamCreator.cs#L98-L100

This is "sync-over-async", which is a [well-known cause of deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). The problem is most likely that the threadpool is blocked with your user code, so the work required to complete `TcpClient.ConnectAsync` can't be queued, so none of the `Task`s can complete, so no code can make forward progress.

You can work around that by forcing the threadpool to have more threads (this worked on my machine, but it may not be a guaranteed solution):

```cs
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500);
// do NOT call ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads
```

You can also switch to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), which implements threading code properly, and doesn't need the `SetMinThreads` workaround in order to run. I've added an example of what using MySqlConnector's async methods [would be like](https://github.com/tedekeroth/ThreadPoolMySqlTests/pull/1). (Disclosure: I am the lead developer of MySqlConnector.)

Comment: Thanks for the input! Sounds about right that the problem is a bug in Mysql.Data. However, it doesn't change anything increasing the MinThreads in the example projekt, I tried that before and there is no change. I will replace Mysql.Data with MySqlConnector! 

Comment: @Ted I downloaded and ran the code on my machine, and using `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500)` (and deleting `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`) stopped the hang. It's definitely a hacky workaround, so perhaps it's dangerous for me to assume it'd always work.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the update. I think the best approach is to replace Mysql.Data with MySqlConnector, so tomorrow I'll do that and see how it fares 