# Does MySql Connection methods support async programming?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio, asynchronous

I'm using a simple method for connecting to a MySql database but connecting to this database takes a while & this causes the app to be in "not responding" mode. 
now, can I use async for solving this?

Script is:

```
Private void button_clicked()
{
MysqlConnection connection = new MysqlConnection(constring);
connection.open();
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551459/mysql-c-sharp-async-methods-doesnt-work may be worth a read.

Comment: Mjwills: thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At the end, I found the exact answer according to @MikaalAnwar's answer!

> We don't need to add any new options (like `Asynchronous Processing=true`) to connection string; That's for SQL connections & doesn't work for MySql.

So, what should we do now?

> we make any void that is respected to have async option, `async`. Then we add an await task & run it (`Task.Run`). inside that task, we do what ever we want with our connection.

for example: (We don't want to use any datasets)

```
private async void DBConnect(String connectionString)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
        { 
            MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            dbConnection.Open();
        }
    );

}
```

> & We don't use `DBConnection.OpenAsync()`because the void is async & we've used await for the task.

Finished:)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Connector/NET (i.e., MySql.Data) exposes the async ADO.NET methods, e.g., `MySqlConnection.OpenAsync`, `MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync`, but these methods all execute synchronously. This is a [longstanding bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111) in Connector/NET.

**Edit (April 2023):** [MySQL Connector/NET 8.0.33](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/news-8-0-33.html) has been released and provides true asynchronous implementations of the `Async` methods.

You can get asynchronous database operations by switching to MySqlConnector ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), [GitHub](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector)), an OSS alternative that provides asynchronous I/O and higher performance.

Comment: But I solved it! With Mysql.Data it's better to work with tasks & it doesn't have any problem in async performance.. @bradleyGrainger

Comment: If you have to use MySql.Data and you are invoking it from a UI thread, then using `Task.Run` is the only way to move that work to a background thread. But in general, using `Task.Run` to make blocking work asynchronous is a bad idea in most environments: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html

Answer (score 0):

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync() performs synchronous whereas MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync() performs asynchronous

Answer (score -1):

I am sure that’s possible. In addition to structuring your code like the following ([source](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1121822/Using-Async-Await-Task-Methods-With-SQL-Queries-NE)):

```
public Task<DataSet> GetDataSetAsync(string sConnectionString, string sSQL, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var newConnection = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString))
        using (var mySQLAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sSQL, newConnection))
        {
            mySQLAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            if (parameters != null) mySQLAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            mySQLAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
            return myDataSet;
        }
    });
}
```

This combined with the use of “await” keyword, will get you the results you need.

```
//Use Async method to get data
DataSet results = await GetDataSetAsync(sConnectionString, sSQL, sqlParams);
```

Also update the connection string by adding “**Asynchronous Processing=true**” connection property ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming))

I would also recommend you to have a look at the “**OpenAsync**” method. You can read more about it in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection.openasync?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Using `Task.Run` to offload blocking code to the threadpool is a bad idea: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html Instead, use MySqlConnector https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector to get true asynchronous DB operations. Finally `Asynchronous Processing=true` is a SQL Server connection string option; it will throw an error if you try to use it with MySQL.

Comment: You shouldn use Asynchronous Prossesing option in connection string... thats right, thats for Sql and not for Mysql... but i tried this: 1.made the related void async 2. Made a task and run it 3. Made the task await 4. Put all the connection proccesses inside the task... and it works well @bradeyGrainger