# MySqlConnector MySqlConnection.OpenAsync() not working

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms Android app, which needs to connect to a MySQL database.

I decided to use MySqlConnector, because it has async methods.

However, when I call `OpenAsync()` it throws System.IndexOutOfRangeException.

`Open()` works fine, but I would like to use async. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
private static MySqlConnection DBConnection;

internal static async Task<bool> SetAndTestConnectionString(string dbendpoint, int userid, string password)
{
    DBConnection = new MySqlConnection($" *connection string* ");
    bool connectresult= false;
    try
    {
        await DBConnection.OpenAsync();
        connectresult= true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        connectresult= false;
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
            
    return connectresult;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `SetAndTestConnectionString` in turn?

Comment: @GSerg `bool connectionsucceeded=await SetAndTestConnectionString();` Of course I supply the arguments. If the arguments I pass are incorrect, the exception it throws is somthing like "Cannot connect to host". So I don't think it has much to do with how I call it.

Comment: In that case, are you sure it's `OpenAsync` that throws this exception? Are you using the official MySql connector (that [doesn't really support async](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34032153/11683)) or [something else](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector)?

Comment: @GSerg I'm using the "something else". And yes, I'm sure it is what throws the exception. See also this [github issue](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/1116)

Comment: Well, yes, they receive a zero-sized memory span and try to access the first byte. Not much you can do about that.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for trying to help.